# Which DatetimePicker is more suitable for internet explorer

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, datepicker

I want to use a datetime-picker in my project. There are lots of library, plugins and scripts are available to use but not any of it providing proper support for Internet Explorer

I have tried:

- [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html)
- [Gijgo-Datepicker](https://gijgo.com/datepicker)
- [Pickadate.js](https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/)
- [MalotFr](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

From above this I will prefer "bootstrap-datepicker" because other two are falling back in some functionalities and giving errors

I believe there are more other scripts, plugins and libraries to use datetime-picker.

Once I used any one of this, it is cumbersome to switch later. 
That's why the question arises Which should I prefer to use??

Comment: Firstly note that plugin recommendations are off-topic for SO. Secondly, which version of IE? Lastly, I believe the jQueryUI datepicker works down to IE6, you just need to use a legacy version of jQuery.

Comment: It depends what is your requirement and which plugin is best suitable to fulfill your specific needs. You can choose it based on your requirement and if you get any issue in the code than you can let us know about that. We will try to check the issue and try to provide suggestions for it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If it is off-topis on SO,  where should I ask it? and I am using IE 11 (sorry, forgot to mention that ) . I dont know why but ht JqueryUI datepicker is not running on my side. It say " the object  does not support datepicker method or property"

Comment: Any of those libraries will work in IE11. If you have an issue with implementing them please ask a new question giving specific details about what functionality is not working for you and any errors you receive

Answer (score 1):

I prefer bootstrap-datepicker over all of them. Actually, which version of IE are you using? I am using

Version: 11.555.17763.0

Comment: I am using the same

Comment: Working fine for me. what is the version of your bootstrap-datepicker?

Comment: I am using the latest one may be v1.8